# Esri File Geodatabase The parameter is (or has) the wrong kind of geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, error

One of my tools was having problems, during debug I encountered a new error based on FDO error codes:

```
Case -2147220982
    fKnownErrNum = "The object has been deleted and is no longer valid."
```

Attempting to edit the feature class in ArcMap:
[image]

Which suggests that the data editor (somehow) has inserted a geometry that isn't the expected PolyLineZ into the table.

I tried to remove the bad shape with a tool I wrote but on the line `pFeature = pFeatCur.NextFeature` I get this error message:

[image]

Theoretically it should be impossible to insert a row with an incorrect geometry into an Esri file geodatabase, which has me scratching my head and wondering, but academics aside the data represents capture time and I would like to salvage if possible what I can. So far I have tried Repair Geometry, my own tools (with obvious failure) and the usually reliable Export to XML workspace document - which returns a similar error to editing in ArcMap.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue to this and been able to redeem (even partially) the data?

Comment: In Python i'd use try except pair going with search cursor and build a tuple of failed oids. Open table select oid in tuple, delete features

Comment: That's a good idea @FelixIP, I'll give that a shot. I was thinking something like build a list of OIDs then attempt a make feature layer with a query by each OID with a try/except and export each; the problem with this is the only way I can think of to enumerate the OIDs is via a search cursor which fails with a similar error on for row in cursor: Can you think of another way to enumerate the OIDs without a cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on a new numeric field

```
def isWrong(shp):
 try:  b=shp.firstPoint.X;  return 0
 except: return 1
```

## -------------------------

```
isWrong( !Shape!)
```

and select records with 1. Note you can delete features using tool outside editing session.

If the outcome are 0s only, I afraid there something else, not a bad shape.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work, the DB is corrupt (I'm getting values that contain non-printing characters) any attempt to write to the table fails with same or similar errors (editing is worse than non-editing, the table is blank with 'unable to load data' error). This is why we keep backups; only a few hours were lost as the other tables/feature classes are accessible. It seems this error message is *the tolling of the bell* for this database.

Comment: That was my feel

Comment: Nice try anyway, it didn't help in this case but might work in a slightly different case for someone... I'll call this one accepted as it lead me to the realization there was no hope for the data.